# InternalError TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

**Dears, I can't get started with TensorFlow, Even if I ignore this error ,another command doesn't work.I have cut the whole error, only the beginning and some sentences kept.I hope experienced beginners will understand the problem.Please help anyone.**

```
import keras 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

**Using TensorFlow backend.
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Universe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Universe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Universe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Universe\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Universe\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

................................................................................
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'


TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Comment: That error message is quite common, have you looked at the many resources available on the subject? Please provide the contents of the environment.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a missing directory from the %PATH% environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by downloading and installing visual studio 2017-2019 x86 and x64 from here:

Other solution is downgrading tensorflow to 2.0:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0
```

I have Python 3.7.6, CUDA 10.1 and cuDNN for CUDA 10.1 and I have followed this requeriments: